# How to write NULL instead of 0 when I leave a field empty

Tags: php

I have a problem with inserting data. When I leave a field empty then he writes a 0 in my db instead of 0. What I have to do that he writes NULL.

```
<?php

if ($date == '' || $name_home == ''|| $name_away == '')
{

$error = 'Please enter the details!';

valid($date, $name_home, $name_away, $score_home, $score_away, $error);
}
else
{

mysql_query("INSERT name_matches SET date='$date', name_home='$name_home', name_away='$name_away', score_home='$score_home', score_away='$score_away'")
or die(mysql_error());

header("Location: view.php");
}
}
else
{
valid('','','','','','');
}
?>
```

Comment: is this data being POSTED to this PHP script?

Comment: set the field to ` NULL DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: If the field is set to accept null then the default type should be null already, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html `If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause`. What is the column(s) you are trying to set currently (type and default)? `0` sounds like it is an `int` column..

Comment: Check your db table. Set allow null option for that field & remove default value if it set to 0. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It's been solved and can be closed.

```
mysql_query("INSERT name_matches SET date='$date', name_home='$name_home', name_away='$name_away', score_home=IF('$score_home'='',NULL,'$score_home') ,score_away=IF('$score_away'='',NULL,'$score_away')") or die(mysql_error());
```